Threatening queens
Two queens placed on a chessboard are said to threaten each other if the two lie in the same row, column or diagonal, and there are no other queens on the line segment between them.

For which positive integers k does there exist a positive integer n and an n×n chessboard with a non-zero number of queens such that each queen is threatened by exactly k other queens?

For which positive integers k can you place a non-zero number of queens on an infinite chessboard such that each queen is threatened by exactly k other queens?



Can the number of queens in part (2) be infinite?

@ilikecorgis I guess so, otherwise you would be able to do it on a finite chessboard anyway.

@Pranay Fair point.

For the finite board, we can get

 1, 2, 3, or 4 attacks

with

 these formations

 5 or higher isn't achievable. Consider the topmost occupied row, and the leftmost queen in it: it can only have queens to attack to its right, and the three downward directions, short of the 5 it needs.

For the infinite board, we can get

 any number 1 to 8

How?

 We get 1 through 4 attacks with the finite setups, 5 with two full infinite rows of queens, and 8 with a queen in every cell. This leaves 6 and 7. But, our construction for 6 and 7 will be general enough anyway to handle any number from 2 to 8.
 We'll use a just-do-it-proof. We'll describe an infinite process to satisfy the constraints of each queen in turn, the limit of which will produce a board that meets the conditions.
 Start by placing a queen somewhere. Maintain a queue of queens that need to be "satisfied", that is, to get the desired number of queens to attack. Start the queue with just the initial queen. Take the first unsatisfied queen, and draw one ray from it (from among the 8 directions a queen attacks) for each additional queen that's needed to satisfy it. Along each ray, place a queen that's far enough that it doesn't attack any of the already placed-queens, and add that new queen to the queue. Note that because only finitely many queens have been placed at each step, there's always a position along the infinite ray that doesn't attack any of these earlier queens.
 If, say, we want each queen to attack 7 others, then the starting queen with have 7 rays, and each following queen will have 6 rays since it already gets one attack from its "parent" queen that spawned it (and we avoid the parent's direction for the new rays). Our construction avoids any accidental attacks between two queens, so there will never be an issue where a queued queen already attacks too many queens, or where a newly-placed queen adds an unwanted attack to an earlier satisfied queen.
 The final board is the limit of this process, which has infinitely many queens. That is, a queen in placed on each square where there exists a step on which a queen is placed there. Even though every finite step of the process has unsatisfied queens, every queen is added at a finite position in the queue and so is satisfied at that step, and further steps will never ruin it being satisfied. So, all queens are satisfied in the limiting construction.


As a relatively simple shape for k=6, you can also take a thick cross without the intersection. (In other words, the symmetric difference of two orthogonal lines of width two).

A fractal pattern similar to Sierpinski's triangle satisfies $k=7$: Step 1 is one queen. Step 2, place queens above and to the right. Step $n$, repeat the pattern so far $3^{n-2}$ squares above, and $3^{n-2}$ squares to the right. The limit of this process is all in one quadrant. Reflect it to four copies to use the full plane.

@aschepler can you give a diagram please.

Small improvement in your generic method, you only need to avoid satisfied queens.

@Laska I put it in a non-answer answer.

The answer by @xnor shows nicely which cases are and aren't possible. This additional comment is too large for a comment.
For k=7 on the infinite board,

here's a fairly nice explicit solution


 


 This is a fractal, where the distances from the blue queen to the green queens are $1, 3, 9, 27, \ldots$. Each queen sees one empty diagonal ray away from the center. (Also, every empty square is threatened by at least one queen.)


 Consider just the upper right quadrant, including the blue queen and all queens above it and/or to its right. The fractal there is similar to the Sierpinski triangle: to build it iteratively, place the blue queen, then replicate 1 square above and 1 square to the right for a total of 3 queens, then replicate that pattern 3 squares above and 3 squares to the right for a total of 9, then replicate 9 squares above and 9 squares to the right, etc. The other three quadrants are reflections of that whole process, placed "back to back".

Proof:

 Mathematically, with the blue queen labeled $(0,0)$, the upper right quadrant fractal can also be described as the set of points when the $x$ coordinate and the $y$ coordinate are both sums of zero or more powers of $3$, with the same number not appearing more than once in the same sum nor in both sums: $\left\{\left(\sum_{i\in A} 3^i, \sum_{j\in B} 3^j\right) \mid A \cup B \subset \{0,1,2,\ldots\}, A \cap B = \emptyset \right\}$.
 ($3^0=1$ can be a term in the sum, and the case $A=\emptyset$ and/or $B=\emptyset$ allows $x=0$ and/or $y=0$.) The other three quadrants are the reflections mapping $(x,y)$ to $(-x-1,y)$, $(x,-y-1)$, and $(-x-1,-y-1)$.


 Suppose queen $Q = (x,y)$ is in the upper right quadrant, with $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$, and the coordinates are sums of distinct powers of three. Five of the eight directions are simple:
  $Q$ is threatened from the right: we can always add a power of three not already in use to the $x$ coordinate to find another queen to the right. That queen might not threaten $Q$ because of other queens in between, but it's still true $Q$ is threatened by exactly one queen from that direction.
  $Q$ is threatened from above: similarly, add an unused power of three to $y$.
  $Q$ is threatened from the left: its own reflection $(-x-1,y)$ is to the left. Again, if $x>0$ that's not the directly threatening queen, but that doesn't matter.
  $Q$ is threatened from below: A reflection of $Q$ is at $(x,-y-1)$.
  $Q$ is threatened from the lower-left diagonal: There is also a queen at $(y,x)$, and its reflection at $(-y-1,-x-1)$ is in that direction from $Q$, since $x-(-y-1) = y-(-x-1)$. 


 Notice for any integer $b$, the line $y=x+b$ includes the coordinates of exactly one queen in this upper-right quadrant. It's straightforward to prove by induction that using powers of three no larger than $3^n$, there is a unique valid pair $(x,y)$ such that $y-x$ is each integer in the range $-\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2} \leq y-x \leq \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$. (This relates to the balanced ternary representations of integers.) So without the bound $3^n$, the possible pairs represent each integer difference exactly once. So finally,


  $Q$ is NOT threatened from the upper-right diagonal: Any queen there would be in the same quadrant and on the same $y=x+b$ line.
  $Q$ is threatened from the upper-left diagonal: There is exactly one queen $Q_2=(z,w)$ in the upper-right quadrant with $w-z=x+y+1$. It has a reflection at $Q_3=(-z-1,w)$ in the upper-left quadrant. $Q$ and $Q_3$ are on a line with slope $-1$ since $x+y = (-z-1)+w$.
  $Q$ is threatened from the lower-right diagonal: Again with $Q_2=(z,w)$ and $w-z=x+y+1$, there's also a queen at $Q_4=(w,z)$ in the upper-right quadrant. It has a reflection at $Q_5 = (w,-z-1)$ in the lower-right quadrant. $Q$ and $Q_5$ are on a line with slope $-1$ since $x+y = w+(-z-1)$.


 So $Q$ in the upper-right quadrant is threatened by exactly 7 other queens. The same is true of queens in the other quadrants by symmetry.


I oddly feel like someone should feed this into Golly... I'd love to see the output.

@ConnieMnemonic Paste https://pastebin.com/3zsLsuZJ into https://golly.sourceforge.io/webapp/golly.html . That's 6 iterations of the fractal, enough so that the rest of the evolution will be copies of pieces of this one's. At step 2213, there's nothing but stable shapes, blinkers, and gliders that will meet in pairs. The pairs either annihilate or produce 6 blinkers (some close to, but not interfering with, older stable shapes). But since the times before the gliders meet is unbounded, the whole infinite pattern is never truly periodic.

Aren't you a gem? Wow. It's very pleasing to see in motion and surprisingly long lasting. Thank you!

Fun fact: You can generate the quarter of the board by placind a queen at (x,y) where x, y and x+y do not use the digit '2' in the ternary representation.

I've got another pattern for 7:

 

 Each segment extends one cell further, eventually occupying all diagonal lines of sight.  Each queen sees another queen in all directions except for the obvious horizontal or vertical one.

And one last thing...

 Each cell whether empty of occupied is threatened by exactly 7 queens.


This is a much easier position to prove, nice

But I still prefer the fractal pattern.  It is pretty cool.

Crazily, you can omit any number of queens. Place an orthogonal rectangle centred on the origin, and remove all the queens underneath. Since the remaining pattern of queens is still symmetric, the property of 7 attacks still holds

Another variation is that the lengths of the straight segments can follow any increasing sequence and that sequence can be different for each corner.
